# Rails Hash Format

Tags: ruby, hash

Which is the preferred hash format for Rails? Or is one of them wrong?

```
User.create(:name => "John")
```

or

```
User.create(name: "John")
```

Can I do

```
User.create(:name "John")
```

or

```
User.create(name: => "John")
```

Comment: best way to learn is by doing, open rails console and try each

Comment: I did. the last two didnt work. Not sure why.      update: Boris explained it. But still not sure why the placement of ":" matters a lot!

Comment: I don't think Rails has particular preference. If there is any preference, then that is Ruby's preference. Don't confuse Ruby with Rails.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? Is that a stupid question for a newbie? I mean, come on!I am still learning....!

Comment: It does not get downvoted for being stupid, but it can be downvoted for being lazy. The reason for downvote in this case is probably because you can easily get answer by looking the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to realise the semantics of the different symbols.

In here:

```
User.create(:name => "John")
```

You have a symbol `:user` mapped with linking operator`=>`.

In here:

```
User.create(name: "John")
```

You have linking operator `:`.

These two are wrong:

```
User.create(:name "John")
```

Here you have symbol and then no link from key to value at all.

This too:

```
User.create(name: => "John")?
```

You have two links once `:` and once `=>`.

I think your biggest issue is that you do not completely undertand the meaning of symbols in Ruby. Read [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm).

Comment: I mean when ":" is on the right, no "=>" is required. Why is that?

Comment: This is alrearnative linking symbol. Rather you need to realise the semantics when it is on the left. see the link i have added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Boris. Appreciate your swift and great help!

Answer (score 1):

The ruby 1.9's way is to do `User.create(name: 'John')`. The older fashion is to do `User.create(:name => 'John')`. Other solutions will not works.

Comment: It is not Ruby 2's way. It is Ruby 1.9's way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ruby >= 1.9 syntax for hashes. Prefer { a: :b } over { :a => :b }.

If you want to study rails, I highly recommend a git repo(https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide), it can help you write good style rails code, hopefully useful to you.